# Hard coded blue values are black in my minimal vulkan triangle application

Tags: vulkan

I'm following the guide at vkguide.dev and at the moment I have just a small triangle displaying on my screen. However, it seems that I have messed up something with how colors are represented.
When I hardcode the triangle to be blue (`fragColor = vec4(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f)` and set the background to red via the ClearValue in my renderpass, my triangle looks like this:

[image: Triangle with black instead of the expected blue with a red background]

Another weird behavior is that with a blue background (which works if I use it as a clearValue), my red triangle (`fragColor = vec4(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f)` turns into pink:

[image: Pink triangle on blue background]

The tutorial I am using recommended the [vk-bootstrap](https://github.com/charles-lunarg/vk-bootstrap) library to set up Swapchain-, Device-, Queue- and Vulkan Instance creation, so there might also be a default in there which does not work with my setup.
I'm on Linux with the proprietary Nvidia driver, but hopefully none of that is the issue here.

Comment: Can you post your pipeline setup? This looks like a wrong or accidently activated blend state.

Comment: Ah you were right, I missed setting the bit for the blue channel in the colorWriteMask of VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState. Thanks a lot! Not sure how to mark this as solved now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments: The problem was caused by a wrongly setup pipeline color blend attachment state with a missing bit for the blue channel in the color write mask. This caused the triangle to seemingly change colors depending on the clear color for the render pass.